# SwiftUI withAnimation causes unexpected behaviour

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I noticed a strange behaviour of XCode using swiftUI's `withAnimation{}`.

I created the following working example:

```
import SwiftUI

class Block: Hashable, Identifiable {
    // Note: this needs to be a class rather than a struct
    
    var id = UUID()
    
    static func == (lhs: Block, rhs: Block) -> Bool {
        lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(self.id)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var blocks: [Block]
    
    init() {
        var blocks = [Block]()
        
        /// generate some blocks here
        blocks.append(Block())
        blocks.append(Block())
        blocks.append(Block())
        
        self._blocks = State(initialValue: blocks)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(blocks, id: \.self) { block in
                BlockRow(block: block) { b in
                    print("COMMENT THIS LINE OUT") // try commenting out this line -> XCODE won't build anymore
                    
                    withAnimation {
                        self.blocks.remove(at: self.blocks.firstIndex(of: b)!)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BlockRow: View {

    @State var block: Block
    var onDelete: (Block) -> Void = {_ in}
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("<Block>")
            .onTapGesture {
                print("Tap block \(block.id)")
                self.onDelete(block)
            }
    }
}
```

The above example works as expected, if you click on one of the blocks it get's deleted and the following blocks will nicly slide in the free position.

But XCode produces a warning here, I do not understand:

> Result of call to 'withAnimation' is unused

Things get even more confusing: by just commenting out the print stamenet beforehand the withAnimation block `/* print("COMMENT THIS LINE OUT") */` XCode will no longer build the project:

> Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please file a bug report

Is this a bug or am I completely off-road with my aproach?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The origin of the problem is the fact that `self.blocks.remove(at:)` returns a value that you are not handling.  If you explicitly ignore that value, then your code works as expected whether or not the `print` statement is there.

```
withAnimation {
    _ = self.blocks.remove(at: self.blocks.firstIndex(of: b)!)
}
```

Swift has a feature that a closure with a single line of code returns the value of that statement as the return of the closure.  So in this case, if you don't ignore the return value of `remove(at:)` it returns a `Block` and `Block` then becomes the returned type of the `withAnimation` closure.

`withAnimation` is defined like this:

```
func withAnimation<Result>(_ animation: Animation? = .default, _ body: () throws -> Result) rethrows -> Result
```

It is a *generic* function that takes a closure.  The return type of that closure determines the type of the generic placeholder  which in turn determines the return type of `withAnimation` itself.

So, if you don't ignore the return type of `remove(at:)`, the `withAnimation<Block>` function will return a `Block`.

If you ignore the return value of `remove(at:)`, the statement becomes one that has no return, (that is, it returns `()` or `Void`).  Thus, the `withAnimation` function become `withAnimation<Void>` and it returns `Void`.

Now, because the closure to `BlockRow` has only a single line of code when you delete the print statement, its return value is the return value of the single statement, which is now `Void`:

```
BlockRow(block: block) { b in
    withAnimation {
        _ = self.blocks.remove(at: self.blocks.firstIndex(of: b)!)
    }
}
```

and this matches the type that the closure to `BlockRow` is expecting for its `onDelete` closure.

In your original code, the `print` statement caused the closure to `BlockRow` to have 2 lines of code, thus avoiding Swift's feature of using the single line of code to determine the return type of the closure.  You did get a warning that you weren't using the `Block` that was being returned from the `withAnimation<Block>` function.  @Asperi's answer fixed that warning by assigning the `Block` returned by `withAnimation<Block>` to `_`.  This has the same effect as my suggested solution, but it is handling the problem one level higher instead of at the source of the problem.

---

**Why doesn't the compiler complain that you are ignoring the return value of `remove(at:)`?**

`remove(at:)` is explicitly designed to allow you to discard the returned result which is why you don't get a warning that it returns a value that you aren't handling.

```
@discardableResult mutating func remove(at i: Self.Index) -> Self.Element
```

But as you see, this lead to the confusing result you encountered.  You were using `remove(at:)` as if it returned `Void`, but it in fact was returning the `Block` that was removed from your array.  This then lead to the whole chain of events that lead to your issue.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach(blocks, id: \.self) { block in
            BlockRow(block: block) { b in
                _ = withAnimation {
                    self.blocks.remove(at: self.blocks.firstIndex(of: b)!)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tested with Xcode 12.0 / iOS 14

Comment: That perfectly works. Thx! Do you have any idea why it behaves like this? I see that withAnimation has a return type, but why is it effected by weather there is a print statement or not (the print statement can btw be substituted by any other call). Also I noticed that the whole issue is not existant if Blocks would be a struct rather than a class.